# CountDown Timer Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, timer

I m working on online examination i just wnat to start timer at exam start and want to end as exam finish  i hv endtime on my cotroller and i m passing that endtime on view i want to start timer between system time and end time

Controller

```
public ActionResult TestStarted(int TestId,DateTime End_Time)
        {
            ViewBag.ct = 0;
            ViewBag.TestId = TestId;

            EAssessmentNew.BAL.StudentBal studBal = new EAssessmentNew.BAL.StudentBal();
            EAssessmentNew.Dal.Student_Answer_Master _studAnsdal = new       EAssessmentNew.Dal.Student_Answer_Master();


            ViewBag.EndTime = End_Time;
        }
```

View

```
<script type="text/javascript">





    var days, hours, minutes, seconds;


    var countdown = document.getElementById("lblCtime");


setInterval(function () {


    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = ( @ViewBag.EndTime - current_date) / 1000;


    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);


    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
</script>
```

Suppose i have  EndTime 1:00 PM and System Time 12:00 PM how can i start timer betwwen these two times as i want to convert my EndTime 1:00 PM into milliseconds as current date in my script returns me time in milliseconds.

Comment: what you want to do exactly?

Comment: how do i get server time..? and where to pass it

Comment: i m working on online examination and i just want to start timer as per the exams duration suppose my start time of exam is 12:00 PM and End Time is 1:00 PM i just want to start timer of 1 hour between these two times

Comment: when ever user click on give exam button you need to store that into the table and get the time and reduce it with the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is whenever the user click on the Give Exam add the time to the Duration of exam that you are going to give him (i.e Exam Start Time 1PM and you are giving user to 1 Hour of Time to Complete the Exam then you need to pass the date with the time 1PM + 1 HOUR More so it will count from that datetime to finish the exam) and pass this as End date with this function

```
<script>
    var end = new Date('08/14/2014 12:00 PM');

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
```

The end date will automatically count based on the server datetime and you need not to worry about the local time.

[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/oj8wguwx/1/)

## [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/oj8wguwx/2/)

Comment: do i need to include any javascript for this

Comment: yes jquey.js file or any jquery file that is latest (i.e, jquery.min.js or any version of this but i suggest you to use jquery.js)

Comment: var end = new Date('14-08-2014 1:00:00 PM') this is my format and your script is giving me error when i use this format

Comment: and i need to pass end time from database as i want clock on each and every page as m loading one question on one page at a time so each and every time new page is called i need to pass end time from database

Comment: plz check the updated demo and you can pass the end date from backend, you need to replace 14-08-2014 1:00:00 PM from demo to your date and then try it in all the page but use separate script for each pages

Comment: just take a look what i m doing on server side "string EndTime= String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}", End_Time);" i m trying to set the format of my date in your format and everything seems fine it just that i m not getting the seprerators i.e "/" on server side my output of above code is as "08-14-2014 01:00 PM"

Comment: then split with var dateAr = '14/08/2014 1:00:00 PM'.split('/');

Comment: as you wish but be careful not to raise any error plz ;) :)

Comment: "0hrs 26mins 45secs0hrs 26mins 44secs0hrs 26mins 43secs0hrs 26mins 42secs0hrs 26mins" but as i remove them it keep on incrementing with every second

Comment: thank u brother but i hv done the same thing what u hv done i not getting it where the problem actually was by the way its working fine now thank u

Comment: problem is with the += check it you will find it, it's appending the whiole by that

Comment: yes got it every time it concates the whole format thanks 1 again

Comment: as i m working on online examination i want clock to start at server time otherwise any body can change the time of their system and increase the exam duration if u know then plz help me how can i get server time

Comment: when user click on Give Exam you need to do entry in one table that particular user has started the exam with the start time and that start time is your server time and then you need to pass in the jquery and process it accrdingly with this you can find how many students are givingg exams at particular time